# Block level backups of Docker volumes

Tags: backup, docker

I'm new to Docker and trying to evaluate methods and processes for doing backups on a CentOS host and container. From reading numerous articles about Docker backups, I've come to the following conclusions:

1. No one does block-level backups of Docker volumes, only file-level.
2. The backup process can run from the host or from a backup container, but if run from a container has no way to access underlying devices (by definition of containers).

I completely understand the second point, but is (or why is) it not possible to get consistent block-level backups from a volume? I would think that a volume backed by LVM could be snapshotted from the host and backed up appropriately.

Comment: A docker volume is a directory on the host.

Comment: No one does block-level backups **on Ubuntu** because Docker on Ubuntu uses AUFS. Other distributions don't have this problem.

Comment: I updated the question to specify that I'm running a CentOS host and container. However, on Ubuntu I believe only containers are backed by AUFS and not volumes-- they are simply directories on the host that are accessible in the container. This would suggest that even on Ubuntu a volume could reside in a directory backed by LVM or even btrfs and could be backed up at the block level.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout ClusterHQ's [Flocker](https://docs.clusterhq.com/en/latest/introduction.html), it leverages ZFS snapshot replication over the network.

Comment: CentOS support is currently work-in-progress, you will need to upgrade the kernel etc. More information can be found in ClusterHQ's Jira: https://clusterhq.atlassian.net/browse/FLOC/component/10007 https://clusterhq.atlassian.net/browse/FLOC-999